# Show that $\frac{\sin(mx)}{\sin(x)}=\sum_{j=0, j\equiv 1\pmod 2}^m\binom{m}{j}(1-\sin^2(x))^{(m-j)/2}(-\sin^2(x))^{(j-1)/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Show that $$\frac{\sin(mx)}{\sin(x)}=\sum_{\underset{j\equiv 1\pmod 2}{j=0} }^m\binom{m}{j}(1-\sin^2(x))^{(m-j)/2}(-\sin^2(x))^{(j-1)/2},$$
where $m$ is odd. I did as:

If $z=e^{ix}$, then,
$$\frac{\sin(mx)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\Im(z^m)}{\Im(z)}=\frac{z^m-\bar z^m}{z-\bar z}=\prod_{k=1}^m(z-\zeta _m^k\bar z),$$
where $\zeta _m$ is a primitive root of $X^m-1$.

Any idea on how to conclude ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
\begin{align}
\sin(mx) &= \operatorname{Im} (e^{ixm}) \\
&= \frac{(e^{ix})^m - (e^{-ix})^m}{2i}  \\
&= \frac{(\cos x + i\sin x)^m - (\cos x - i\sin x)^m}{2i} \\
&= -i\sum \limits_{{\small\mbox{odd}} \ \  j} {m\choose j}(\cos x)^{m-j} (i\sin x)^j\\
&= -i\sum \limits_{{\small\mbox{odd}} \ \  j} {m\choose j}(1 - \sin^x)^{\frac{m-j}{2}} (-\sin^2 x)^{\frac{j}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing it out!